# How to pass just one part of a state through context provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have this state and I want to pass just `showForm` of my state through `MyContext.Provider` and not whole state. When I put `state.showForm` as part of value property, it doesn't accept this type. How can I do that?

```
const [state, setState] = useState({selectedValue: {term: '', city: ''}, input: '', showForm: false})
.

.

<MyContext.Provider value={{formTitle, state.showForm, handleShowForm}}>
    <MyChildComponent />
</MyContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer immediately after asking, I just used a name for that:

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{formTitle, showForm: state.showForm, handleShowForm}}>
    <MyChildComponent />
</MyContext.Provider>
```